# Translate assembly declaration from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

I'm trying to create my 1st SignalR project using VB.NET and *not* C# (my bad).

I'm currently stuck with this piece of code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
```

Can someone tell me how to write this in proper VB.NET?

Comment: You can use ILSpy to easily look at assemblies as C#, VB.net and IL. It usually creates rather verbose versions of code though.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```vb
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(SignalRChat.Startup))>
```

I used the [Telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com).